# Image Magick produces two PDF pages from a single TIFF with convert

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

with Debian and this version of image magick:

```
convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

I am having a weird issue, I run this command:

```
convert tiff.tif tiff-no-absolute-path.pdf
```

And I get a PDF with two pages when I expect a single page PDF:

```
convert -verbose tiff.tif  tiff-no-absolute-path.pdf
tiff.tif[0] TIFF 241x117 241x117+28+89 8-bit Grayscale Gray 9640B 0.010u 0:00.004
tiff.tif[1] TIFF 295x295 295x295+0+0 8-bit TrueColor sRGB 0.010u 0:00.003
tiff.tif=>tiff-no-absolute-path.pdf[0] TIFF 241x117 241x117+28+89 8-bit Bilevel Gray 0.050u 0:00.032
```

Not sure why but it splits the image in gray scale and in RGB... ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

`tiff` can have multiple layers - which yours seem to have - and by default each layer is separated during conversion. Merge them as follows:

```
convert input.tif -layers merge output.pdf
```

Comment: Also there is probability (just speculate) the TIFF is multypage and this cause separation